# SSAS Time Series, predict when something will fail

Tags: ssas, mdx, time-series

I would like to use SSAS and a TimeSeries Mining Structure to predict when the predictable value will reach a certain threshold.

For Example:

```
SELECT [Info Key],
PredictTimeSeries([Free Space], 200) as ForcastedSize
FROM [Drive Module Information]
WHERE ForcastedSize < 10000 --(<< this does not work)
```

This will tell me the date that it forecasts that the drive space will be below 10000.

How do I write an MDX query to accomplish this?
Thanks,
Brian

**UPDATE 1:**
I think I can accomplish it this way, with some limitations:

```
SELECT [Drive Module Information].[Info Key],
    (SELECT *
    FROM PredictTimeSeries([Drive Module Information].[Free Space], 5000) as [FUTURE]
    ) AS T
FROM [Drive Module Information]
  WHERE
  [Info Key] = 'MyMachine C:' AND
     [Free Space] <     10000
```

The limitation is that I can only look X# of steps forward without getting crazy.  Which is ok.  I am ok with knowing that the drive will not fill up over the next week, or month.

I did not figure out how to use FILTER in this situation, and am still curious as to if there is a "What date will this predictable value be equal to this value".

**UPDATE 2:** I have come to the conclusion that SSAS was not meant to do this, so until I find out differently, I will mark icCube as the answer since he helped out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MDX is not SQL, the where clause of MDX is not a real filter. As a quick introduction you can go through this [MDX gentle Tutorial](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx_tutorial/gentle_introduction.html).

There is a [MDX Filter function](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Filter.html) you can use.

Comment: Ok, since the where is a slicer and MDX is not a SQL query, what kind of hint can you give me on how to get (or even if SSAS is the right place for) the information I want?

I want to look forward in the time series to find the point where the forcasted value is zero.

I thought that maybe sub-queries in MDX might help, but I cannot seem to get that through my thick head either.

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: Filter() function is what you're looking for, sub queries too but better not using them